# Why do I get the error "expected integral variable, found Option" when matching on an integer?

Tags: rust, match

I am trying to use `match` in Rust. I wrote a function:

```
fn main() {
    let try = 3;
    let x = match try {
        Some(number) => number,
        None => 0,
    };
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         Some(number) => number,
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected integral variable, found enum `std::option::Option`
  |
  = note: expected type `{integer}`
             found type `std::option::Option<_>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         None => 0,
  |         ^^^^ expected integral variable, found enum `std::option::Option`
  |
  = note: expected type `{integer}`
             found type `std::option::Option<_>`
```

I tried something like `let try: i32 = 3;` to make sure that `try` is an integral value, but I still get the same error.

Comment: the compiler tell you the opposite: it expect an integer but you give him an Option. Why to you want match `try` a integer variable with `Some` and `None` a Option variant ?

Comment: So is it an error concerning `x` and not `try`? I thought that in my case, match returned either 3, which is an i32 or 0, which is also an i32?

Comment: Did you read the book ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
fn main() {
    let try = Some(3);
    let x = match try {
        Some(number) => number,
        None => 0,
    };
}
```

The issue is that you're trying to match an integer against `Some(...)` and `None`, which are `Option`s. This doesn't really make sense... an integer can never be `None`.

Instead, I think you want to use the type `Option<i32>` and convert it to an `i32` by using a default value. The above code should accomplish that. Note that if that's all you're trying to do, this is an easier way:

```
let x = try.unwrap_or(0);
```

Comment: Thank you, unwrap_or is what I was looking for. Would this also work on a Result, meaning that it would return a 0 if the Result was an Err? Or would it return Some(Err)?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `Result` implements [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or) with the same semantics.

Answer (score 1):

In `match` expressions the type of the value you are matching on must correspond to the variants in the block following it; in your case this means that `try` either needs to be an `Option` or the `match` block needs to have integral variants.

I highly recommend reading [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/); Rust is strongly typed and this is one of the most basic concepts you will need to familiarize yourself with.